# logical operations on large files binary data in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I have two binary files (order of tens of MB) and I want to or every bit of these files. And of course, I want it to be as efficient as possible.

So I have two ways in mind to do that, but I still think (I kinda feel) that should be a more efficient way that I do not know of.

Given file a and b .. what I want to do is a = a|b

1. Loading two files, parse them in to two huge std::bitsets and or them together
2. loading two files byte by byte and or them if a huge for loop...

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't go byte-by-byte. That'd be seriously slow. Instead, read the files in chunks. Find what the block size is for your system (4k? 8K? 64k?) and read the file using chunks of that size. Then you can loop through the byte streams in memory and do the OR operations there.

In logical terms, even though you might only be reading a byte at a time, the OS will still read an entire block worth of data, then throw away all but the byte you wanted. Next time around that block'll be cached, but it's still going through the full read motions for every byte you want. So... just suck the entire block into memory and save yourself that wasted overhead.

Comment: +1 I concur. If you don't mind holding the entire file in RAM, you could stream/load the entire thing, and then iterate through bytes or words and do the bit-wise operations there. Also, sequential disk access is much faster than random, so it may be good to grab as much as possible at one time.

Comment: As I do not really have memory limitation, I can read all on memory once and then or them byte by byte using a for loop! is it what you are suggestiong the best?

Comment: Reading in block-sized chunks will always be more efficient than going byte-by-byte. But regardless of disk system details, there's absolutely no reason to do `or` on 8bits at a time. 32bit machines can do that 32bits at a time in the same number of cycles as it'd take for the single byte.

Comment: @Marc B: you can add this recommendation (about or-ing native integers instead of bytes) to the answer body. It has comparable impact on performance.

Comment: Well this is what I am going to do: Load my files in char * .. cast every 8 bytes to a long integer (I have 64bit machine) and or them together, and write them back to the file...

Comment: Yes, use unsigned type of int of the size that matches your machine (64-bit in your case). You can check that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is in fact 8 bytes on your machine/compiler.

Comment: Don't assume or check. Just cast every `sizeof(unsigned long)` bytes to `unsigned long`. Oh, and don't forget to special-case the last few bytes.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend loading the two files a chunk at a time, where a chunk is some appropiate portion of the data. The best size would depend on your operating system and filesystem, but its usually something like the cluster size, or 2 * the cluster size, or so on... You would have to run some test to determine the best buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would have any performance advantage either way (if in your "second option" you are going to load the file in big chunks), after all you'd be using a big stack-allocated buffer in both cases (which is what `std::bitset` boils down to), so go with the one you like best.

The only advantage I see in the `std::bitset::operator|=`, besides clarity, is that it may be able to exploit some platform-specific trick to or big sequences of bytes, but I think that the compiler would be able to optimize your big "or loop" anyway.